# WGET is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, wget

I am simply trying to download a file from github, but my `wget` command is not being recognized. I am unsure what is going on. I've read that I should use `urlopen` instead, but I run into the same error.

[image]

Comment: can you try `python -m wget` instead of `wget`?

Comment: Thank you. This worked!

Comment: why do I have to call python is I am already running anaconda?

Comment: If you `pip install wget`, it makes `wget` a python module, for which you need `python -m` to run (`m` is for module).

Comment: Great Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` is usually provided with unix / linux operating system. It seems you are on windows, so you can:

- Download it for windows (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) and put in in your `PATH` environmnent variable
- Use cygwin (https://www.cygwin.com) / babun
- Use Docker

Also, `wget` only "download" a file. If you need it for only a few files, you can download them manually.

Answer (score 1):

To install and configure wget for Windows:

1. Download wget for Windows (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) and install the package.
2. Add the wget bin path to environment variables (optional).  Configuring this removes the need for full paths, and makes it a lot easier to run wget from the command prompt:
   Open the **Start** menu and search for “environment.”
   Select > **Edit the system environment variables**.
   Select the **Advanced** tab and click the **Environment Variables** button.
   Select the **Path** variable under **System Variables**.
   Click Edit.
   In the **Variable value** field add the **path to the wget bin** directory preceded by a **semicolon (;)**. If installed in the default path, add **C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin**.
3. Open the **command prompt (cmd.exe)** and start running **wget** commands.